# Material UI Autocomplete with Avatar in textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Can I achieve `avatar` in the `textfield` of [autocomplete material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component as the `getOptionLabel` prop only accepts a string and render option the expected UI is shown .i.e profile picture and Name, can we get the same thing i.e profile picture and name in the `renderInput` `textField`

Comment: Did you try the suggested answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can return your custom component in renderInput props, and that custom can be a combination of icon and TextField Like this...

```
renderInput={(params, data) => (
  <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
    {params.inputProps.value && (
      <span
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          transform: "translateY(50%)",
          marginLeft: "5px"
        }}
      >
        {/* Write logic to have Icon from params.inputProps.value */}
        {countryToFlag("AD")}
      </span>
    )}
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Choose a country"
      variant="outlined"
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        autoComplete: "new-password",
        style: { paddingLeft: "20px" } // disable autocomplete and autofill
      }}
    />
  </div>
)}
```

As you can see I have provided the Absolute position `span` which will render the icon based on the selected value(I am still not able to find a way to access the options object).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-microservice-w0hix?file=/src/component.js:1179-1981) is the complete and running [sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-microservice-w0hix?file=/src/component.js:1179-1981)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is by using an [adornment](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#input-adornments), if the input is controlled:

```
<Autocomplete
  // ...
  value={selected}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        startAdornment: params.inputProps.value && (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <Avatar>{selected}</Avatar>
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

It should look like this, without the need for margin/padding changes:

[image: A dropdown element with the label 'select someone', showing an avatar component on the left with the initials 'BY', followed by the text 'BY']